# Why can't Finder quicklook the mp4 I just encoded with ffmpeg?

Tags: macos, finder, video, big-sur, encoding

I just did `ffmpeg -i My\ Movie.mov vid.mp4` to convert iMovie output to an MP4.

I can't quicklook the mp4 as usual (by pressing space), nor does Finder show a thumbnail for it.

Here is `ffmpeg -i` information for a quicklookable mp4:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'playable.mp4'
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:21.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 746 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 612 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Here is `ffmpeg -i vid.mp4`:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'vid.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : My Movie
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    keywords        : iMovie
  Duration: 00:00:53.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 316 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:2:2) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv422p10le, 480x270 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 190 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 119 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
```

How am I meant to use ffmpeg to turn My Movie into an MP4 that can be quicklooked?

Comment: On **macOS Catalina** I just created a movie with **iMovie** and it was saved as an **MP4**, so no need to convert. Does **macOS Big Sur** save a movie created  with **iMovie** as **MOV** by default, can it also do **MP4** so as not to need **FFmpeg**?

Comment: @user3439894 maybe it can save to mp4. How do I convert this mov to a quicklookable mp4 though?

Comment: On my install of **macOS Big Sur** I do not have **iMovie** so I cannot do any testing under **macOS Big Sur** unless I download it, which I do not want to do, sorry. As to the issue at hand, without having a sample **MOV** _file_ that exhibits the issue, I have nothing to test with to see if I can analyze the issue, sorry.

Comment: @user3439894 here is an input and `ffmpeg -i My\ Movie.mov vid.mp4` output https://we.tl/t-PnNI2JM9WY

Comment: If you want a workaround, open the **MOV** in **QuickTime Player** and export it, then use **FFmpeg** and the resulting **MP4** will be **QuickLook** playable. Otherwise, you'll probably have to play around will additional **FFmpeg** _options_ for the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have the same issue, but in my case, the problem was that the
`handler_name` cannot be more than **29 characters**. To fix, you could try a
command like this instead:

```
ffmpeg -i 'My Movie.mov' -metadata:s handler_name=SoundHandler vid.mp4
```

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3623